# QMediaPlayer and QVideoWidgets status

Tags: qt, qmediaplayer

How can I check the status of a QMedia object if it is running or not?
I want to stop player as soon as I close my vw. There is the code for my player and vw :

```
 QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer;
 QVideoWidget* vw = new QVideoWidget;

 player->setVideoOutput(vw);
 player->setMedia(QUrl("C:/Users/Hafiz/Documents/AddingVedio/HangManShot1.wmv"));
 vw->setGeometry(100,100,800,600);
 vw->show();
 player->play();
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to show us more code, is this inside your `main()` function? Do you really need to allocate `player` and `vw` in the heap? As a quick and dirty work around, you can declare `player` as a child to `vw`, and then `vw->setAttribute(WA_DeleteOnClose);`. This will guarantee that both `vw` and `player` are destroyed (and thus `player` is stopped) as soon as `vw` is closed. But if you show more code, I think that there should be a cleaner solution.

Comment: '#include "tutorial.h'
#include "ui_tutorial.h"
#include<QMediaPlayer>
#include<QVideoWidget>
Tutorial::Tutorial(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Tutorial)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    player = new QMediaPlayer;
    vw = new QVideoWidget;
    player->setVideoOutput(vw);
    player->setMedia(QUrl("J:/TheHangMan/videos/HangManShot1.wmv"));
    vw->setGeometry(100,100,400,500);
}
Tutorial::~Tutorial(){
    delete ui;
}void Tutorial::on_open_clicked(){
    player->play();
    vw->show();
}' @Mike.
i tried this. but when i close my vw window music goes on.